# Conflicts between endpoints in Node.js with express application

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

First of all, i have searched the solution to this problem and i didn't found anything. Sorry if it's duplicated.

I have in my express+node.js app two endpoints like this:

```
// Gets a tweet by unique id
app.get('/tweets:id', function(req, res, next) {
    // Response management
});

// Gets mentions of user unique id
app.get('/tweets/mentions', function(req, res, next) {
    // Response management
});
```

The problem is that requesting a GET petition to *"/tweets/mentions"*, is attended first by *"/tweets/:id"* and later by *"/tweets/mentions"*, making a conflict.

I have tried to change the declaration order of the endpoints, but always the request is attended by both endpoints.

Also I have tried things like *"/tweets::mentions"*, but I need to access the endpoint via *"/tweets/mentions"*, and I suppose there is a possible way.

How can i resolve this conflict?
Thanks.

Comment: One question: how do you pass the unique id in '/tweets/mentions/' endpoint?

Comment: You should use `/mentions` to have a proper REST design.

Comment: @MatteoTosi i have a JWT in one header that allows me to search his user id in the database.

Comment: @PavelGatnar Thanks, i was thinking about it. But i'm interested in how to resolve this problem too, cause i have the same problem with other endpoints.

Comment: @rpfc try using something like '/tweets/user/:id' as first endpoint. For routes with additional parameters is always recommended to not use the same base path of other routes.

Comment: @MatteoTosi thanks for your feedback, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using `next()` in one of the  handlers?

`next()` passes control to the next matching route, so in your example, if one of them is called and inside it you call `next()`, the other one will be called.

I allways recommend to use 'Router' if you have more than one base path because it helps you to keep it organized.

Comment: Thanks for your response, using router and not using next() was the solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve the conflict by checking the value of `req.params.id` in the "tweet by id" handler.

Comment: Thanks i will consider this for further problems!

Answer (score 0):

For routes with additional parameters is always recommended to not use the same base path of other routes.

Something like could work for you:

```
app.get('/tweets/users/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    // Response management
});

// Gets mentions of user unique id
app.get('/tweets/mentions', function(req, res, next) {
    // Response management
});
```

Comment: Thanks, are answers are valid, thanks for your contribution, i will take account of all of these answers.